# What to do with wrong answers?

Tags: discussion

Some answers seems to be wrong.

When reviewing the "Low Quality Posts" queue we are asked if:

> *This is an honest attempt at answering the question and is not low quality.*

How should we read it if we believe it is a honest attempt but wrong?

- Should we recommend deletion?
- Should we consider OK and leave a comment to the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule, if someone is honestly trying to answer a question but provides a wrong answer the best course of action is to downvote and/or leave a comment explaining why you believe the answer is wrong. First off, you may be wrong in thinking the answer is wrong, and secondly this gives the poster a chance to fix their answer and/or learn from their mistakes.

It's also a lot less harsh; if someone is answering a question then they're trying to help out. They may not be helpful at all, but outright deletion is a pretty strong response IMO, little more than "buzz off".

A (rare) exception to this are answers that are just spectacularly wrong. "What is two plus two?", "Your answer is bulldozer!" Arguably that's not really "wrong" because it just makes no sense.

Comment: Downvoting + a comment is good to explain not only to the person answering but also anyone who comes across it. Saying why an answer may be wrong also helps explain and teach others more about the subject.